# Find Value of textarea from closest row of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a button Update in One td I want to fetch value of both textarea of td from same tr.
There are lots of tr so I have to use `closest()` method to find element. I have tried to find element but it's not working.

**HTML :-**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="agenda-date">
            <div class="dayofmonth color_font_date">2017-05-31</div>
            <div class="dayofweek">
                Wednesday                                            
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="row margin_two_planner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">AM </button> 
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#add_apt_status" class=""><input type="number" value="3" name="" class="number_planner"></a>
            <label class="control-label"> 6 </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin_two_planner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">PM </button> 
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#add_apt_status" class=""><input type="number" value="4" name="" class="number_planner"></a>
            <label class="control-label"> 2 </label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 20%;"> 
            <textarea id="" class="form-control initial_cap appointment_note" required="required" rows="3" name="appointment_note" cols="50" aria-required="true" disabled=""> APT -1 </textarea>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 20%;"> 
        <textarea id="" class="form-control initial_cap holiday_note" required="required" rows="3" name="holiday_note" cols="50" aria-required="true" disabled=""> Holiday - 1 </textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-primary appointment_edit_button">Edit </button>
            <button type="button" id="" onclick="planner_note_edit(1)" class="btn btn-md btn-primary appointment_update_button" style="display:none"> Update </button>
            <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-md btn-cancel appointment_cancel_button" style="display:none">Cancel </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Jquery :-**

```
function planner_note_edit(planner_note_id)
{

        appointment_note = $(this).closest('td').find(".holiday_note").val();
        alert(appointment_note);
}
```

But I'm not able to fetch value of textarea from closest td.

Comment: You are probably looking for `$(this).closest('tr').find(".holiday_note")...`. Note `tr` instead of `td`

Comment: You should find for "tr" element. I normally use $(this).parents('tr').find('.holiday_note').val(). Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `textarea` from current `row`.

So, please use `.closest('tr')`

```
appointment_note = $(this).closest('tr').find(".holiday_note").val();
```

Also, you have to pass the `clicked` button object. `this` in your function is a reference to the `window` object.

```
function planner_note_edit(planner_note_id,event)
{

    appointment_note = $(event.target).closest('td').find(".holiday_note").val();
    alert(appointment_note);
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="" onclick="planner_note_edit(1,event)" class="btn btn-md btn-primary appointment_update_button" style="display:none"> Update </button>
```

Comment: Thanks you for reply. It's also not working it showing me undefined. I have tried with `$(this).closest('tr').find(".holiday_note").val();` May be it's because I'm in one td and I want to fetch value from another td ? I'm not sure for it.

Comment: What you see in console when use `console.log($(this).closest('tr').find(".holiday_note"))` ?

Comment: @Bhavin, I think I got your problem ! Have a look to updated answer.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Thank you for your precious time. :)